# objective-c: when to autorelease an nsnumber object when not using alloc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I noticed that my program was crashing because it was running out of memory. I figured out that this was happening because of this code segment:

```
DataSet *tempSet = [[DataSet alloc] init];          
tempSet.rightFoot = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:temp1];
tempSet.leftFoot = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:temp2];
[footData addObject:tempSet];   //add dataSet object to the array
[tempSet release];
```

I read some tutorials about memory management online and was able to figure out that I needed to do this: (notice the added "autoreleases")

```
DataSet *tempSet = [[DataSet alloc] init];          
tempSet.rightFoot = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:temp1] autorelease];
tempSet.leftFoot = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:temp2] autorelease];
[footData addObject:tempSet];   //add dataSet object to the array
[tempSet release];
```

I am still confused about why I had to do this. I did not use alloc, new or copy when creating the numberWithDouble.

Does this mean that I would need to add autorelease in this situation as well?:

```
[subset addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:temp]];
```

What about this situation?:

```
tempSet.rightFoot = [NSString stringWithString:@"temp"];
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+numberWithDouble
```

is called a *convenience method*.  Meaning, it replaces the little section of code that would look like this:

```
[[[NSNumber alloc]initWithDouble:double]autorelease];
```

Most (if not all) convenience methods are auto release by default, so the OP code with the autoreleases is incorrect, as it drops the retain count to -1.

The equals sign however is equivalent to

```
[self setRightFoot:[[[NSString alloc]initWithString]autorelease]];
```

which increments rightFoot's retain count and requires it to be released elsewhere.

as for the `-addObject` code, it returns void, so it does not in fact increment the receiver's retain count, and requires no release of the receiver.  The object in the array should already be released by the convenience method for later, which doesn't matter because the array is now holding "copy" of it.

Comment: Absolutely!  Any more questions?

Comment: I am debugging my code a bit more and this now seems to be causing it crash: NSNumber *newX = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:tempX/doubleScaleX] autorelease];   can you explain why?

Comment: Like I explained above, `+numberWithDouble` is already autoreleased, so when you autorelease it again, it's retain count will ultimately become -1.

Comment: But I thought you said that when there is an equal sign you need use autorelease because (in this case) it will increment newX's retain count?

Comment: No, the value itself is being assigned to newX (which increases retain count from 0 to 1), then you autorelease it, which decrements it from 1 to 0.  Then it is autorelease by the convenience method which decreases it from 0 to -1

Comment: Okay so I think I understand. Let me just make sure. So the only reason I need to autorelease rightFoot and leftFoot is because they are not NSObjects and I didn't create a dealloc method to release them. And in the case of NSString (or NSNumber) *value = ["some convenience method"], the NSObject class will take care of releasing it.

Comment: Sort of... assigning a variable a value directly (equals sign, or setFoo:bar) increments the retain count of the object (just like alloc and init), and autorelease decrements it, but only in the case of methods that aren't autoreleased themselves.  Don't you just hate manual memory management?  Use ARC, for the love of god, just use ARC and skip this headache.

Comment: haha. I don't really know what ARC is but Google seems to be telling me it's a feature of Xcode 4 which I sadly do not have... I'm working on a work computer that they won't allow me to upgrade. It seems as though this is something that is automatically done in ios5? Is this true?

Comment: No, it's actually a feature of the compiler, which is why it requires Xcode 4.2+.  I highly recommend you request an upgrade because when you fall behind on the SDK's, it's fairly hard to catch up.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will definitely be bugging my boss about this tomorrow :).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer (I just do not know how to comment -- I only see "share, edit, flag"), but just a few info about Memory Management in iOS:
1. Don't release objects that you do not own.. ---> owned objects are usually the ones you "alloc", "new", "copy." //And probably the one in your @property wherein you "retain" an object.
2. when you "autorelease" an object, don't "release" it afterwards, because that would mean you're releasing the same object twice.

But there's ARC already, so you better upgrade your Xcode to avoid overreleasing objects / memory leaks (for not releasing objects)..

If there's something wrong or inappropriate with the one I put here, please edit. :)